# Calling python from php fails when import numpy

Tags: php, python, numpy

Trying to call a python (2.6) script from php when a make a GET HTTP request from Android, but if the import numpy is in my script, I get a failure, if I remove it, the script/call works.  I am computing the FFT spectrum of a numeric field in MySQL, so I need numpy (or do I?).

I've look at similar questions on SO, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704519/php-script-cant-get-output-from-python-script) one, answered by @dietrich-epp, is the best one but when I try the same suggestion, my script still fails.

Here is my imports part of my python script:

```
import  os, os.path, sys
import numpy
import string
import math
import MySQLdb
```

And the start of my PHP file:

```
<?php
putenv('PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages:');
...
```

And this how I call my python script:

```
$command = "/var/www/html/tremcam/tst0.py localhost baseline@nd.edu 2>&1";
$pid = popen( $command,"r");
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 #echo fread($pid, 256);
 print(json_encode(fread($pid, 256)));
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);
```

And my environment variables have the PYTHONPATH set to:

```
/var/www/html/tremcam/pythons
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python26.zip
/usr/lib/python2.6
/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info
```

Should this (`PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`) be pointing at `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy` instead?

I will try using passthru() instead of the way I currently have it in PHP.  Please note, that after I am able to import numpy as np, the code will take several seconds to complete, will that also be an issue?

Update:  if I use: `passthru('/var/www/html/tremcam/tst0.py localhost baseline@nd.edu 2>&1',$result);`

I get exit status code 139, so that isn't very helpful to me, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Try with 
`setsebool httpd_tmp_exec on`
if it works make it permanent with 
`setsebool -P httpd_tmp_exec on`

It should be SELinux denying Apache your pytonpath directories (and yes you should provide the very numpy folder if it still doesn't work, but it shouldn't be necessary at all).

A slightly less clean approach is to comment this line `import ctypeslib` in `/<your numpy path>/numpy/__init__.py`

I had the same problem and both the approaches worked fine (the latter though may lead to some inconsistency in later developments therefore I suggest you to try setsebool first)