# Is it possible to stop a python script from php?

Tags: php, python

My task is fairly simple to explain

Build a web interface which allows to:

- start a python script if the "go button" is hit (+ deliver some parameters). this should be possible with something like `exec('python /path/to/myScript.py param1 param2')`
- (list running instances of this script - I currently don't know how to do this but its more of a nice-to-have)
- **terminate a specific instance of this python script if the "stop button" is hit**

Just to clarify: There is no public access for the web interface calling the python script. After the script is started it should run an infinite amount of time until manually stopped by a user.

Webserver: apache 2.2.22
OS: ubuntu 12.04.2
python: 2.7.3

Comment: you could manage your script using supervisor http://supervisord.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't really know much about how lining python with PHP would work, but this is how I would approach the problem. It seems like it's pretty simple to get a list of running processes in python [(sample)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python). And it should be equally easy to get the output from python [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704519/php-script-cant-get-output-from-python-script). So I assume it shouldn't be hard to terminate a running process having its PID.

So in terms of the question, create 3 python scripts:

1. one to start a process
2. second to get a list of processes with a given name / path / whatever
3. third to terminate it.

This way you can control all the actions and stuff.